# Related Dropdown list on PHP

Tags: php, ajax

i want to retrieve dropdown list data "kabupaten" which is related to last dropdown list "Provinsi" but i can't, here my code 'index.html

```
<?php
 require_once("dbcontroller.php");
 $db_handle = new DBController();
 $query ="SELECT * FROM provinsi";
 $results = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
?>
<html>
<head>
<TITLE>jQuery Dependent DropDown List - Countries and States</TITLE>
<head>
 <style>
body{width:610px;}
.frmDronpDown {border: 1px solid #F0F0F0;background-  color:#C8EEFD;margin: 2px 0px;padding:40px;}
.demoInputBox {padding: 10px;border: #F0F0F0 1px solid;border-radius: 4px;background-color: #FFF;width: 50%;}
.row{padding-bottom:15px;}
 </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"             type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script>
 function getState(val) {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "get_state.php",
data:'idprov='+val,
success: function(data){
    $("#kabupaten-list").html(data);
}
});
}

 function selectCountry(val) {
 $("#search-box").val(val);
 $("#suggesstion-box").hide();
 }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="frmDronpDown">
     <div class="row">
  <label>Provinsi:</label><br/>
    <select name="provinsi" id="provinsi-list" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getState(this.value);">
     <option value="">Select Provinsi</option>
   <?php
     foreach($results as $provinsi) {
    ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $provinsi["id_prov"]; ?>"><?php echo $provinsi["provinsi"]; ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </select>
     </div>
      <div class="row">
      <label>State:</label><br/>
        <select name="kabupaten" id="kabupaten-list"     class="demoInputBox">
     <option value="">Select State</option>
  </select>
  </div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

In index.html we get data from user and parsing it to get_state.php 
And here my get_state.php

```
<?php
    require_once("dbcontroller.php");
    $db_handle = new DBController();
    if(!empty($_POST["idprov"])) {
        $query ="SELECT * FROM kabupaten  WHERE id_prov = '" . $_POST["idprov"] . "'";

        $results = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
    ?>
        <option value="">Select State</option>
    <?php
        foreach($results as $kabupaten) {
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $kabupaten["id_kab"]; ?>"><?php echo $kabupaten["kabupaten"]; ?></option>
    <?php
        }
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: What values get POSTed to `get_state.php`? Use the console to see

Comment: first i have dropdownlist(1) data provinsi, and then in the dropdownlist(2) data i want to get kabupaten data which related to provinsi (dropdownlist(1)).

Comment: Is the data actually being POSTed to `get_state.php`?

Comment: Try to var_dump your $_POST["idprov"] - I'm pretty sure it will be empty, and use @RamRaider method of posting Paramus in jQuery

Answer (score 1):

I do not use jQuery so I could well be wrong but I believe the data you send in your ajax POST needs to be in object literal notation, ie `{param:value}` - so more like this:-

```
function getState(val) {
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"get_state.php",
        data:{ 'idprov':val },
        success: function( data ){
            $("#kabupaten-list").html( data );
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: by the way if i want to add some related, how i must to do? for example, Kecamatan dropdownlist related to Kabupaten, kabupaten dropdownlist related to provinsi @RamRaider

Comment: use the same methodology, though you would need to ensure that the second dropdown is populated before allowing third dropdown to be selectable